# Checkbox onclick not firing

Tags: html, checkbox, onclick

I'm at my wit's end with this.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this line? The function won't fire by clicking on the checkbox for some reason, but the calling function works fine (if I copy the exact "onclick" attribute over to the label for the checkbox, it works fine).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="match_35_0" id="match_35_0d" value="d0" onclick="checkSwap(document.page_form.match_35_0d, document.page_form.match_35_0)"></input>
```

If anyone can see why on earth this wouldn't be working, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Since a couple people asked, here's the checkSwap function (all it does is throw an alert so I can see that my onclicks are working before I add any code):

```
function checkSwap(radioid, groupid) {
alert("radio: " + radioid + " group: " + groupid);}
```

And here's the whole sample of the table cell that the checkbox in question is in (apologies for the formatting, the code sample doesn't seem to want to accept my newlines):

```
<td><label onclick="checkSwap(document.page_form.match_34_0d,document.page_form.match_34_0)" for="match_34_0">N</label><input type="checkbox" name="match_34_0" id="match_34_0d" value="d1"  onclick="checkSwap(document.page_form.match_34_0d, document.page_form.match_34_0)"></input></td>
```

EDIT: Alright, canceling out a separate function that was limiting the checkboxgroup to 1 checked box was the issue.

The code that does the limiting was setting an onclick attribute for each checkbox, and that is apparently overriding the tag-set attribute. I'll have to figure out how to hack around it.

Comment: You must have a function called "checkSwap" declared somewhere, can you post that code?  Also look into Firebug for Firefox for some good javascript debugging tools.

Comment: Unsure why clicking wouldn't work, but have you tried binding to "onchange"? For a checkbox, the behavior should be identical.

Comment: There is no end tag for `input` element

Comment: Does this fail in all browsers?

Comment: Have you tried a different function (`alert("Test")`, for example) in place of that function?  Are you using a debugging tool (Firebug, IE Developer Toolbar), do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Stefan: IE doesn't work too well with `onchange` for checkboxes, in fact, it's not even listed in the documentation for `input type=checkbox`.

Comment: onclick works just fine with checkboxes; @javanix - post your checkSwap function.

Comment: The checkSwap function doesn't do anything except fire an alert. I've tested that it works by putting that same "onclick" code on the label tag for that checkbox.

I've tested in Chrome and Firefox in Linux, and neither Firebug or Developer Tools throw an exception on click - its like the onclick isn't even being evaluated for some reason.

Comment: There's something else going on here elsewhere in your page. It might be as simple as malformed HTML near your checkbox. Make an SSCE (smallest self-contained example) of the error without any of the additional cruft on your page and you'll see it works fine. More information will help people help you.

Comment: @javanix, it might be worth heeding @dev-null-dweller's comment: *there is no end tag for* `input` *element.* If your DOM is broken/poorly-formed from erroneous (x)html you'll find this tends to adversely affect both JS and CSS.

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but your input is in a form named 'page_form' right? Just to be sure

Comment: @ricebowl, @dev-null-dweller - I got rid of the </input> issues, still doesn't fix the problem.

I have two different things affecting that checkbox group - I have a separate function that restricts it to one total selected box, could that have anything to do with it? It still doesn't explain why sticking the same onclick on the label works though.

Comment: The end tag is only required if you declared HTML as XHTML (which I don't recommend though as you apparently aren't using a XML tool to generate HTML pages). As to your problem, please post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org), thus from `<html>` until with `</html>` with the **minimal** code which reproduces exactly this problem, so that we can just copy'n'paste'n'run it to see it ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax

```
document.page_form.match_35_0d
```

actually searches in the form with **name** of `page_form` for an input element with **name** of `match_35_0d`. But you have actually set it as an **id** of the checkbox where the onclick is definied.

You could solve your problem with the following call in the onclick:

```
checkSwap(this, document.page_form.match_35_0)
```

By the way, a checkbox is not the same as a radiobutton and you're actually not passing the ID's to the function, but instead the **whole** elements. Rewrite your function as

```
function checkSwap(checkbox, group) {
    var checkboxId = checkbox.id;
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        var element = group[i];
        var elementId = element.id;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

To obtain an element by ID, just use [`Document#getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById).

```
var element = document.getElementById('someId');
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that (haven't done much JS, as I'm sure you can tell).

You have me passing in 'this' as an argument - it makes sense called from the checkbox's onclick property. However, what would be the correct syntax for accessing that specific checkbox by id? I have a label that I'd also like users to be able to click on to somehow run my checkswap function - from what I can tell, the easiest way for me to do that would just to be to call checkbox.onclick, but I'm not sure how to point at the specific checkbox object by id.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('id')`.

Answer (score 2):

Incase you already have Jquery's ready function then Onclick attribute of the ckeckbox will not fire. You have to add the click event in Jquery. Only then it works
Like below. I don't know the reason.

```
$('#cbFinalAttest').click(function (event) {  
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer.  The question does not contain jQuery, so your answer should discuss HOW to include/use jQuery, then the ready function, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If JQuery's ready method is already defined then Chek box onclick event do not work. You can fire the event if you add a Jquery click event inside ready. Not sure if this is IE issue ..?

Answer (score 0):

this function does fire - checked in firebug

```
<input type="checkbox" name="match_35_0" id="match_35_0d" value="d0" onclick="alert('55')"></input>
```

you have to check 'checkSwap'

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier to pass in `this` to the function, then the parameter would be a reference to the element that called the function. So you can do:

```
function checkSwap(self){
    alert(self.id);
}
```

Edit: Also, `document.page_form.match_35_0.id` will get the id, not the way you have it.